# Обрезать текст при вставке из буфера обмена

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть определенный html в буфере обмена

```
<img src="http://this.site-tt.ru/photos/opacity.png" class="ke ke-D83DDE12" emoji="D83DDE12" style="background-image: url(&quot;../img/emoji.png&quot;);">
```

есть текстовое поле, предположим, обычный параграф (р), куда я вставляю текст их буфера обмена. Можно сделать так, чтобы я вставил уже отформатированный html (с обрезанной ссылкой, и удаленным атрибутом 'style'):

```
<p contenteditable="true"><img src="/photos/opacity.png" class="ke ke-D83DDE12" emoji="D83DDE12"></p>.
```

Либо, сделать так, чтобы копировался в буфер он уже отформатированным, как в "p"

Comment: Каким образом эта разметка попадает в буферобмена? Простое копирование или средствами execCommand('copy')? Каким образом это вставляется в <p>?

Comment: Ctrl+v, или пкм > вставить, ибо по другому не умею))

Comment: Либо, можно сделать так, чтобы при ctrl+v (или пкм>вставить), этот тег вообще не вставлялся, а только текст

Answer (score 1):

[Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/zkxz3vbc/)

```
Дальше обрабатываешь данные
```

Будь аккуратнее, там фичи es6, в некоторых браузерах особенно старых работать не будет. Можно юзать полифиллы